# EF and [JsonIgnore]: Why do I get an empty dictionary when using an existing type, but not when using an anonymous type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, .net-5

### Question

When using an anonymous type it works, but not when using the type `ClientGroupView`, which is identical to the anonymous type. Why?

I suspect this has to do with the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute - it somehow persists with the *typed object*, but not with the *anonymous object*.

### Background

I've got a many-to-many relationship between **Clients** and **ClientGroups** and a controller that returns the groups for a given client.

The controller method returns Json with an empty dictionary, when I use a *typed object*, but not if I use an *anonymous object*, then it returns the expected Json. I get the same results with both .NET 5 and .Net 6.

When using an anonymous object, the Json returned is:

```
[{
    "group":{ "clientGroupId":1, "groupName":"ClientGroup1" },
    "permissions":{ "rClientGroupClientId":1, "clientGroupId":1, "clientId":1 }
}]
```

When using an object of type `ClientGroupView` (that does not contain any `[JsonIgnore]` attrubutes), the Json returned is:

```
[{}]
```

I both cases `result` is the same, before converting to Json, with return `Ok(result)`.

#### The controller

The controller method that returns the information for a given `ClientId`:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetClientGroups(int id)
{
    var client = await db.Clients.FindAsync(id);
    if (client == null)
        return NotFound();

    // Works when using an anonymous type - the Json dictionary is not empty.
    var groups = db.Entry(client)
            .Collection(r => r.XClientGroups)
            .Query()
            .Include(r => r.ClientGroup)
            .Select(r => new { r.ClientGroup, r });

    // But fails when not using an anonymous type - the json dictionary is empty.
    //var groups = db.Entry(client)
    //        .Collection(r => r.XClientGroups)
    //        .Query()
    //        .Include(r => r.ClientGroup)
    //        .Select(r => new ClientGroupView(r.ClientGroup, r));
            
    var result = await groups.ToListAsync();
    if (result == null || result.Count <= 0)
        return NotFound();
    return Ok(result);
}
```

#### The `Client`

```
public class Client
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public string ClientName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<X_ClientGroup_Client> XClientGroups { get; set; }

    public Client()
    {
        XClientGroups = new HashSet<X_ClientGroup_Client>();
    }
}
```

#### The `ClientGroup`

```
public class ClientGroup
{
    public int ClientGroupId { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<X_ClientGroup_Client> XClients { get; set; }

    public ClientGroup()
    {
        XClients = new HashSet<X_ClientGroup_Client>();
    }
}
```

#### The `X_ClientGroup_Client`

The many-to-many relation between `Client` and `ClientGroup`:

```
public class X_ClientGroup_Client
{
    public int RClientGroupClientId { get; set; }
    public int ClientGroupId { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public ClientGroup ClientGroup { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

#### The `ClientGroupView`

Here is the `ClientGroupView` that corresponds to the anonymous object.  It doesn't contain any `[JsonIgnore]` attributes:

```
public class ClientGroupView
{
    public ClientGroup Group;
    public X_ClientGroup_Client Permissions;
    public ClientGroupView(ClientGroup group, X_ClientGroup_Client permissions)
    {
        this.Group = group;
        this.Permissions = permissions;
    }
}
```

If I remove the constructor and construct the object like I do with the anonymous object, the result is the same.

A solution is to change `ClientGroupView` to contain the fields instead of the classes, but I prefer that it contained the classes instead of the fields of the classes, because it is easier to maintain:

```
// I do not want to use this version of ClientGroupView
public class ClientGroupView
{
    public int RClientGroupClientId { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public int ClientGroupId { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    public ClientGroupView(ClientGroup clientgroup, X_ClientGroup_Client permissions)
    {
        RClientGroupClientId = permissions.RClientGroupClientId;
        ClientId = permissions.ClientId;
        ClientGroupId = clientgroup.ClientGroupId;
        GroupName = clientgroup.GroupName;
    }
}
```

The reason I don't want to use this version, is because it requires more maintenance *and* because the controller is used internally, i.e. I do not need to use a DTO.

Comment: How about (1) making the concrete class fields properties, and (2) using initializer (`new  ClientGroupView { Group = ..., ... }`) instead of constructor?

Comment: @IvanStoev I tried that already, it produces the same result.

Comment: I tried this model, and can't reproduce - neither in EFC 5.0 nor EFC 6.0

Comment: @IvanStoev I found a fix, which I added to the question, but I am not satisfied with it. Thank you for helping.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you for testing it, it made me realize it may have to do with the [JsonIgnore] tag that I omitted. I have modified the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ClientGroupView.Group` and `ClientGroupView.Permissions` are fields, not properties.

Add `{ get; set; }`.

Comment: Do you know why it works with the anonymous object, as they don't have getters and setters, as far as I know?

Comment: Because an anonymous type gets compiled to a type with read-only properties (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/anonymous-types).